# How can I implement this horizontal search result bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I essentially have a horizontal div that populates content from omdb API. It dynamically generates a bunch of search results, and displays them all; however the `overflow: hidden` is active.

I have 2 questions:

1. I have two custom "buttons" that I made with an empty div and icon. I gave it a bit of a box-shadow to give it the illusion that it's hovering. Is it better practice to use a button element instead, or does it matter?
2. My main question is this: I want to be able to navigate back and forth between my search results using my arrow buttons. What would be the best way to implement this? The only thing I can think of is using the buttons to adjust the left or right margins of my search results. (ie. pressing the left button would adjust the margin-left of my results with a negative margin, and the right arrow would adjust it with a positive margin)

However, this feels crude and not very accurate. Meaning with a few extra clicks, the content could be pushed out of the view entirely (either by accident or on purpose).

Is there a way to set this up more efficiently?

Here is some code as an example:

```js
const leftArrow = document.querySelector("#left-arrow");
const rightArrow = document.querySelector("#right-arrow");
const marginSelector = document.querySelector("#nav-margin");
var marginValue = -20;

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  marginSelector.style.marginLeft = marginValue + "px";
  marginValue += -20;
});
```

```css
.scrollbar-container {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px #5e9af9 solid;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.result-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(230, 232, 237, .5);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 1%;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 1%;
}

.margin-start {}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="scrollbar-container">
  <div id="nav-margin" class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>

  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>



  <div id="left-arrow" class="nav-button left-arrow">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i>
  </div>

  <div id="left-arrow" class="nav-button right-arrow">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to write some script code for that. Would you like to do it with pure `javascript` or `jquery` is allowed?

Comment: I would prefer Vanilla Js please. I think I was able to come up with something but I don't think it's efficient. @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Could you please update what you have/tried so far?

Comment: To answer your first question about buttons, even though you can use anything really, using an `<a>` tag is a good practice so that keyboard based users and other specialty devices might actually be able to tab to your controls and use the site, and the browser handles things like the cursor and focus states.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Here you, please check the code snippet. This is a very crude effort on my part, but essentially that's what I thought of.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I have improvised my code; please have a look now. Is what I'm doing the best method of achieving my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written script to move back and forth the search results. You just need to check and adjust the `marginLeft` value for your `marginSelector`. I've added `transition` into the `CSS` of `#nav-margin` so that it looks smooth. `marginValue` is been initialized with `0`. `max-width` of container has been set to `500px` for convenience. When you change your `max-width` do not forget to change it in `addEventListener` for rightArrow. You can also make the value inside if condition to dynamic so that it actually takes the value from `.scrollbar-container`.

Let me know if you have any queries.

```js
const leftArrow = document.querySelector("#left-arrow");
const rightArrow = document.querySelector("#right-arrow");
const marginSelector = document.querySelector("#nav-margin");
var marginRightValue = 0;

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(-(marginRightValue) <= (500+20))
    marginRightValue += -100;
  marginSelector.style.marginLeft = marginRightValue + "px";
});

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(marginRightValue < 0)
      marginRightValue += 100;
   marginSelector.style.marginLeft =  marginRightValue + "px";
});
```

```css
.scrollbar-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px #5e9af9 solid;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-margin{
  transition: all 1s;
}

.result-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(230, 232, 237, .5);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 1%;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 1%;
}

.margin-start {}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="scrollbar-container">
  <div id="nav-margin" class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>

  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="result-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dA3tjxl.gif">
  </div>



  <div id="left-arrow" class="nav-button left-arrow">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i>
  </div>

  <div id="right-arrow" class="nav-button right-arrow">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how I envisioned it would work. I do have a question though: 

In the eventhandler for `rightArrow`, I don't understand the logic behind your `if` statement. Can you explain that portion? 

1. Why is there a negative sign there?
2. Where did the 20 come from?

Comment: 1. `if condition` is just to prevent it from scrolling even after reaching end or start of the `div`. 2. `+20` is just a value to scroll bit more so the last element is completely visible. You can just play around removing those values.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this would be the best response, but:

Point 1 - I don't think it matters here. A `<button>` is meant for a form, from a semantics point of view. For more context, read: https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Point 2 - I can already scroll/swipe from left to right (in your code demo when I run the snippet), using my mouse/trackpad. So having extra buttons to do that job seems unnecessary. I would think rather to make a Javascript carousel (or slider) like effect when clicking the right button takes me to the next "slide", or the next chunk of your results. You could then disable buttons when there is no more content on the right (or left), or have them cycle back to the beginning. Effectively you want to think of a fixed width "slide" window (responsive for different viewports) and "slide" accordingly. Does that make sense for your problem?

Comment: Ah, I think you may be confusing the window of the code snippet itself, versus the size of my div. If you expand the code snippet to a full page, you will find that you cannot scroll left or right, unfortunately.

What you've just described in terms of the Javascript Carousel is what I am trying to accomplish right now, but I am having some difficulty in producing the most efficient method.

Comment: I have improvised my code; please have a look now. Is what I'm doing the best method of achieving my results?

Comment: If you change your `overflow` CSS from `hidden` to `scroll`, you should hopefully not have any problems achieving horizontal scrolling. But, regarding the slider, TBH I've never coded a Javascript carousel myself (from scratching) but it sounds simple enough. You can do it from scratch and use a plugin. A couple of searches: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ (plugin) and https://christianheilmann.com/2015/04/08/keeping-it-simple-coding-a-carousel/ (coding from scratch). Since I'm no expert at making one, why don't you try the latter link for practice, and then apply it to your problem?

Comment: Ah, I am aware that I can just use overflow, but I prefer being able to scroll using my custom buttons. I kind of wanted to create it from scratch, but I will have a look at your links. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, so the second link is for creating from scratch. Keep us posted if you manage to do it.

Comment: The gentleman above has answered my question with the exact results I wanted, if you wanted to take a look. :)

Comment: Just had a look, that's great :) please upvote my answer only if it helped you in any way. Thanks